# Почему страница режется по высоте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Перечитал уже кучу страниц, в том числе и на stackOverflow, но так и не нашел решения своей проблемы. Дело в том, что при высоте html, body и .container равной 100% страница режется по высоте, если количество контента превышает высоту окна браузера, раньше таких проблем не было с теми же свойствами, в чем ошибка подскажите пожалуйста. Перепробовал кучу вариаций со свойствами height, min-height, процентами и vh, проблема остается. Хочу добится чтобы при количестве контента меньшем чем высота окна, элементы были растянуты на высоту всего окна, а при количестве большем, отсутствовала описаная проблема.

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates in nemo molestiae itaque, eligendi dolores doloremque deleniti ipsum tempore, ducimus dolorem quia vitae incidunt at quas atque sapiente saepe aperiam veniam culpa iusto, nostrum laudantium placeat tenetur id. Enim, dolore? Nesciunt temporibus quibusdam mollitia. Possimus debitis laboriosam rerum iusto illum fugit earum, consequuntur molestias explicabo itaque magnam animi molestiae sint dolore asperiores placeat harum. Quam voluptate magnam deserunt dicta, omnis. Quo excepturi impedit ut adipisci, odit accusantium. Sequi dolores facere, neque nam, officiis pariatur harum totam minima laboriosam obcaecati. Quo soluta repellendus doloremque esse eum, quos officiis assumenda, consequatur reiciendis cum, minus repudiandae nesciunt! Aspernatur, sint ex, odit numquam ducimus architecto minus impedit quod fugiat. Explicabo rem laboriosam, inventore accusantium tempore aspernatur delectus vel eveniet deleniti id repellendus a aperiam omnis quia. Aut quidem iusto nemo natus ea eum tempora voluptate sequi voluptatum sapiente? Dolores, nam labore velit explicabo obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Ссылка на JSFiddle с кодом примера](https://jsfiddle.net/hh3Lq556/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Задайте `.container` `min-height: 100%;`, а не `height: 100%;`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


.container {
   background-color: teal;
   min-height: 100%
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates in nemo molestiae itaque, eligendi dolores doloremque deleniti ipsum tempore, ducimus dolorem quia vitae incidunt at quas atque sapiente saepe aperiam veniam culpa iusto, nostrum
        laudantium placeat tenetur id. Enim, dolore? Nesciunt temporibus quibusdam mollitia. Possimus debitis laboriosam rerum iusto illum fugit earum, consequuntur molestias explicabo itaque magnam animi molestiae sint dolore asperiores placeat harum.
        Quam voluptate magnam deserunt dicta, omnis. Quo excepturi impedit ut adipisci, odit accusantium. Sequi dolores facere, neque nam, officiis pariatur harum totam minima laboriosam obcaecati. Quo soluta repellendus doloremque esse eum, quos officiis
        assumenda, consequatur reiciendis cum, minus repudiandae nesciunt! Aspernatur, sint ex, odit numquam ducimus architecto minus impedit quod fugiat. Explicabo rem laboriosam, inventore accusantium tempore aspernatur delectus vel eveniet deleniti
        id repellendus a aperiam omnis quia. Aut quidem iusto nemo natus ea eum tempora voluptate sequi voluptatum sapiente? Dolores, nam labore velit explicabo obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: в таком случае получается что .container выходит за пределы html и body, высота которых по прежнему равна высоте вьюпорта, а не высоте всего окна с контентом, так не должно быть.

Comment: Тогда фон перенесите в body, либо .container оберните в контейнер и в него перенесите фон

Comment: это вообще какой то костыль, на мой взгляд, дело в том что раньше, в прошлых проектах у меня таких проблем не было, не понимаю что случилось, проверил в chrome, firefox, opera результат один, использую normolize.css, но он не вносит никаких изменений,которые могли бы повлиять на данный результат, такое ощущение что в стилях сидит какая то ошибка из за которой тянется эта проблема..

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Попробуйте убрать height у body.

Comment: Если убрать height у body он принимает значение auto и так же как .container начинает вылазить за приделы html. Если убираем height: 100% у html, он также принимает значение auto и растягивается по высоте контента, но НЕ более, а мне нужно чтобы на всю страницу.